# Vue js - vsCode - I get an error when I use v-for?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

[image: vsCode screenCode]

I always get this error when working with v-for. It was not a problem before, but I don't like it because I started using it a lot in my project.

Why does Visual Studio Code give an error when working with vue js, even though I have written the codes correctly?

received error;

> [vue/valid-v-for]
> Custom elements in iteration require 'v-bind:key' directives.eslint-plugin-vue

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide key in the v-for tag.

```
<app-card v-for="item in cards" :key="item.id"></app-card>
```

or

```
<app-card v-for="(item,index) in cards" :key="index"></app-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

As error saying itself, `:key` directive is missing as it should be there while working with `v-for`.

> You don't need a `key` attribute in order to use `v-for`, but it's a good practice, that's why editor intelligence is telling you to add.

Please have a read of the official [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State) of vue.js regarding maintaining state while using `v-for`.